# Statement trying to update records not in sub-select

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query which produces a subset of results from a table.  These results are ~3000 and there are ~230,000 roes in the status table:

```
SELECT ms1.* FROM STATUS MS1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MS.EndDate as MDT, MS.ID, MS.StatusID, MS.StartDate  
    FROM MEMBER M
    INNER JOIN STATUS MS ON MS.ID = M.ID 
    AND MS.StartDate =(SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM STATUS WHERE STATUS.ID = M.ID)
    WHERE MS.EndDate IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MS.ID, MS.StatusID, MS.EndDate, MS.StartDate ) MS2
ON MS1.ID = ms2.ID AND MS1.StatusID = MS2.StatusID
```

It is these records returned from the query I want to update.  I then take the above query and wrap it in an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE STATUS 
SET EndDate = NULL
WHERE EXISTS 
(
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MS.EndDate as MDT, MS.ID, MS.StatusID, MS.StartDate  
    FROM MEMBER M
    INNER JOIN STATUS MS ON MS.ID = M.ID 
    AND MS.StartDate =(SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM STATUS WHERE STATUS.ID = M.ID)
    WHERE MS.EndDate IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MS.ID, MS.StatusID, MS.EndDate, MS.StartDate ) MS2
ON MS1.ID = ms2.ID AND MS1.StatusID = MS2.StatusID
)
```

I get a violation of a unique key constraint on a record that IS NOT in the original select from above, so the update is trying to update a row I am not expecting it to update.  The message I get is:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_status_ID_ENDDATE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.STATUS'. The duplicate key value is (3, ).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the below

```
update MS
set
    MS.EndDate = NULL
from
    MEMBER M
    INNER JOIN STATUS MS 
        ON MS.ID = M.ID 
        AND MS.StartDate = ( SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM STATUS WHERE STATUS.ID = M.ID )
WHERE 
    MS.EndDate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It looks as if this method will work, although the update is still failing due to problems in my data (the sub-query I started with).  Now trying to sort that out.  Thanks.